# How to remove default line generated from windows commandline execution step in jenkins console

Tags: jenkins

Whenever I execute something using the build step "Execute windows batch command", it generates a default line on Jenkins console output.

> cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3211049907090844821.bat

To make my console more clear, I want to hide/remove this line from console output without using any other parsing plugins.

Could you please let me know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this via an option or setting. The only way would be to tweak <s>[hudson.tasks.BatchFile#buildCommandLine()](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/BatchFile.java)</s> [hudson.tasks.Launcher.LocalLauncher#launch()](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/Launcher.java) itself.

Comment: This builds the command line itself. I think the output is generated in [LocalLauncher, l. 916](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/Launcher.java), that is called indirectly from [CommandInterpreter, l. 109](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/CommandInterpreter.java). There is a `quiet` flag inside ProcStarter. that could be utilized However, this flag can neither be set nor is it used (outside tests in Jenkins core).